# Problem on multiple updates on same document in Multi-Doc Transactions of MongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb, transactions

I'm facing lot of troubles in using the multi-document transactions. One of which happens to be - Whenever , there are multiple updates on the same document [in the same transaction], Mongo throws a weird error "`com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 251 (NoSuchTransaction): 'Transaction 1 has been aborted.' on server .....`". I took it in the direction of visibility and adjusted the options for Read and write concerns like

**WriteConcern.MAJORITY , ReadPreference.PRIMARY , ReadConcern.SNAPSHOT.**

I'm using the java driver and the snippet for transaction start is something like below

```
TransactionOptions transactionOptions = TransactionOptions.builder()
.writeConcern(WriteConcern.MAJORITY)
.readPreference(ReadPreference.primary())
.readConcern(ReadConcern.SNAPSHOT)
.build();

ClientSessionOptions clientSessionOptions = ClientSessionOptions
.builder()
.defaultTransactionOptions(transactionOptions)
.build();

this.session = mongo.startSession(clientSessionOptions);
this.session.startTransaction(transactionOptions);
```

Any one has an idea on this error?

Answer (score 4):

In order to get more context about the error, you need to check the logs of Mongodb.

In Mongo shell `mongo`, run `show log global` and you will see why the transaction has failed.

In my case, it was failing for this reason:

```
[startPeriodicThreadToAbortExpiredTransactions] Aborting transaction with 
txnNumber 1 on session ea5e8c8d-ecc2-47ca-8901-55a43143a809 because it has 
been running for longer than 'transactionLifetimeLimitSeconds'
```

This looks like a bug in MongoDB since it should throw a`transactionLifetimeLimitSeconds` error instead, or at least tell you what's the problem.

Comment: A good catch. thanks. From the documentation a transaction is considered to have a duration of *less than a minute*. In my case, there had been a file download which took more than that to finally led to the exception.

Comment: I'm facing the similar issue in my build process. is there any solution available yet?

Answer (score 1):

The transaction might include an operation that modifies the database catalog. I encountered the same error caused due to an `insert` operation on a non-existent collection. The `251` error happens when committing the transaction.

```
my-rs:PRIMARY> use mytest
switched to db mytest
my-rs:PRIMARY> show collections
my-rs:PRIMARY> session.startTransaction()
my-rs:PRIMARY> session.getDatabase('mytest').newcollection.insert({"a":"b"});
WriteCommandError({
    "operationTime" : Timestamp(1554822412, 1),
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "Cannot create namespace mytest.newcollection in multi-document transaction.",
    "code" : 263,
    "codeName" : "OperationNotSupportedInTransaction",
    "$clusterTime" : {
        "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1554822412, 1),
        "signature" : {
            "hash" : BinData(0,"AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA="),
            "keyId" : NumberLong(0)
        }
    }
})
my-rs:PRIMARY> session.commitTransaction()
2019-04-09T15:07:04.695+0000 E QUERY    [js] Error: command failed: {
    "errorLabels" : [
        "TransientTransactionError"
    ],
    "operationTime" : Timestamp(1554822422, 1),
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "Transaction 8 has been aborted.",
    "code" : 251,
    "codeName" : "NoSuchTransaction",
    "$clusterTime" : {
        "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1554822422, 1),
        "signature" : {
            "hash" : BinData(0,"AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA="),
            "keyId" : NumberLong(0)
        }
    }
} :
_getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:25:13
doassert@src/mongo/shell/assert.js:18:14
_assertCommandWorked@src/mongo/shell/assert.js:536:17
assert.commandWorked@src/mongo/shell/assert.js:620:16
commitTransaction@src/mongo/shell/session.js:942:17
@(shell):1:1
my-rs:PRIMARY>
```

Please refer to https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/transactions/#restricted-operations